# Troubles with start up defenition of networking service in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, runlevel

I use Ubuntu 12.04.1.
I put attention that networking script starting in runlevel 0:

```
user@comp:/etc/rc0.d$ chkconfig -l networking
networking                0:on   1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
```

When I try to move it working to appropriate run levels I get error:

```
user@comp:/etc/rc0.d$ sudo update-rc.d networking defaults 
update-rc.d: warning: networking start runlevel arguments (2 3 4 5) do not match LSB Default-Start values (none)
update-rc.d: warning: networking stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match LSB Default-Stop values (0 6)
 System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/networking already exist.
```

What should I do?

Comment: I am not getting your question, actually what to you want to do?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to start it in runlevel 0. I try to start it on runlevels: 2 3 4 5, and I get error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start any service in `runlevel 0` use this command

> [root@localhost ~]# chkconfig --level 0 networking on

`--level` means in which runlevel you want to start the service, in this case its `0`.

`networking` is the service name.

`on` means you want to start the service

To stop use this command

> [root@localhost ~]# chkconfig --level 0 sshd off

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to start it in runlevel 0. I try to start it on runlevels: 2 3 4 5, and I get error.

Comment: @Rodnower `chkconfig --level 2345 networking on` try this command to start in 2 3 4 5 and to confirm try this `[root@localhost ~]# chkconfig --list | grep -i `networking`
`networking  0:on 1:off 2:on 3:on 4:on 5:on 6:off`